# How to change Assembly Version Number using AssemblyInfoTask?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I am trying to automate the process for setting the Version for all DLL's, after spending some time I came to know the `AssemblyInfo` Task with which it can most likely be achieved.

So I went ahead and installed it, specifically version **1.0.51130.0**.

After Installing, I manually added the `Import` Tag (by unloading the each project) of `AssemblyInfoTask` in `.cspoj` files (the solution has more than 35 proj files).

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\AssemblyInfoTask\Microsoft.VersionNumber.Targets"/>
```

Next I modified the `Microsoft.VersionNUmber.Target` file which will be installed in path: `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\AssemblyInfoTask`, and I modified the following section:

```
<!-- Properties for controlling the Assembly Version -->
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyMajorVersion>4</AssemblyMajorVersion>
    <AssemblyMinorVersion>0</AssemblyMinorVersion>
    <AssemblyBuildNumber></AssemblyBuildNumber>
    <AssemblyRevision></AssemblyRevision>
    <AssemblyBuildNumberType>DateString</AssemblyBuildNumberType>
    <AssemblyBuildNumberFormat>01MMdd</AssemblyBuildNumberFormat>
    <AssemblyRevisionType>AutoIncrement</AssemblyRevisionType>
    <AssemblyRevisionFormat>00</AssemblyRevisionFormat>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Properties for controlling the Assembly File Version -->  
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyFileMajorVersion>4</AssemblyFileMajorVersion>
    <AssemblyFileMinorVersion>0</AssemblyFileMinorVersion>
    <AssemblyFileBuildNumber></AssemblyFileBuildNumber>
    <AssemblyFileRevision></AssemblyFileRevision>
    <AssemblyFileBuildNumberType>DateString</AssemblyFileBuildNumberType>
    <AssemblyFileBuildNumberFormat>01MMdd</AssemblyFileBuildNumberFormat>
    <AssemblyFileRevisionType>AutoIncrement</AssemblyFileRevisionType>
    <AssemblyFileRevisionFormat>00</AssemblyFileRevisionFormat>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Next I set the `assemblyInfo.cs` file's version to `1.0.0.0` in every project. Finally I saved and close it, reopened solution, and built. It works like a champ!

Now what want is to customize the Version to `4.0.1053.1` where `10` is the part of year indicator which is 2010 and `53` denotes the week number, at last `1` denotes revision number.

How to achieve this using the `AssemblyInfo` Task? I came across several posts that a new version of `AssemblyInfo` Task is available in Build Extension Pack.

I have installed the **MSBuild Extension Pack December 2010** and its version is **MSBuild Extension Pack 4.0.2.0 Installer**

Answer (score 17):

I do this in Jenkins by having a package build that is parameterised using the List Subversion Tags parameter type. The Subversion tag must follow the version number format (major.minor.revision.build), e.g. `tags/2.0.0.1`. The tag name is then assigned to a Jenkins parameter, e.g. `$VERSION` becomes `2.0.0.1`

I use the `WriteLinesToFile` msbuild task to write out the assembly attribute to a second file alongside the PropertyInfo.cs called VersionInfo.cs. As checked in to source control, this just contains a default version number:

```
// Do not change this. The version is set on package builds only by setting the AsmVersion MSBuild property
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
```

The package build on the build server passes in the version via the AsmVersion parameter:

```
/p:AsmVersion=$VERSION
```

The .csproj file is modified to have a `BeforeBuild` target (Visual Studio creates a commented out one for you):

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <WriteLinesToFile 
        Condition=" '$(AsmVersion)' != '' " File="Properties\VersionInfo.cs" 
        Overwrite="True"
        Lines="[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion(&quot;$(AsmVersion)&quot;)] // Generated by build" />   
</Target>
```

When building in Visual Studio, or without passing in the AsmVersion, your assembly will have a default version of 0.0.0.0. When building in the package build, you will get your desired build number.

Comment: I like this way, a bit fiddly but does not require Community Tasks, I don't get why Versioning of an assembly is so non-obvious

Comment: I never got the Target BeforeBuild to fire... at least no evidence of it because VersionInfo.cs never came into existence.  I found this blog article that has a simpler application of VersionInfo.cs.  That worked for me.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328977/The-Right-Way-to-Version-Your-Assemblies

Comment: Don't use `BeforeBuild` as a name of the task, because it can be overridden by MSBuild built-in task with the same name. To avoid that you can define the task as: `<Target Name="GenerateVersionFile" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">`. You can look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64228153/7585517)

Answer (score 16):

First.. use a globalassemblyinfo.cs that is linked from each project.
Add its as linked file to each project. 
This means you update one file, not 30+ assemblyinfo files...then:

use [MSBuild.Community.Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks)....

Then call

```
<AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"
         OutputFile="$(VersionFile)"
         AssemblyCompany="Company"
         AssemblyProduct="Product"
         AssemblyCopyright="Copyright © Company 2011"
         ComVisible="false"
         AssemblyVersion="$(BUILD_NUMBER)"
         AssemblyFileVersion="$(BUILD_NUMBER)" />
```

Assuming you have something like:

```
<Import Project=".\tasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to where one could find `MSBuild.Community.Tasks`?

Comment: Is there some documentation?

Comment: Used to to have a .chm with it.

Answer (score 6):

As @bruceboughton [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14141239), you can easily generate a version assembly file during compilation without using `MSBuild.Community.Tasks` library:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version>0.0.0</Version>
    <InformationalVersion>0.0.0-dev~commithash</InformationalVersion>
    <VersionFileName>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)Version.cs</VersionFileName>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="GenerateVersionFile" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <WriteLinesToFile
        File="$(VersionFileName)"
        Overwrite="True"
        Lines="
            [assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion(&quot;$(Version)&quot;)]
            [assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersion(&quot;$(Version)&quot;)]
            [assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersion(&quot;$(InformationalVersion)&quot;)]" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="$(VersionFileName)" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Remove definitions of the parameters you specify in the generated file from `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

After that you can specify version by adding a parameter to the msbuild:

```
msbuild /property:Version=1.2.3 /property:InformationalVersion=1.2.3-dev~commithash .\SolutionFile.sln
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update for .NET Core style .csproj files:** If you've come upon this question after having transitioned to the new .csproj format used by .NET Core, you can [just set the Version property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45738761/145173) (no need to to bother with MSBuild tasks).

Answer (score 2):

How I finally got this to work MSBuild version 12 (VS 2013).

1. Used Nuget to get MSBuildTasks Community package
2. Edited my .csproj file and added a path to the import the package:

```xml
<Import Project="..\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\build\MSBuildTasks.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\build\MSBuildTasks.target')"/>
```

3. Figured out the Regex to change just the Revision number in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
(?<=AssemblyFileVersion\("[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.)(\*)
```

which is not XML compatible, so has to be changed to:

```xml
(?&#60;=AssemblyFileVersion\(&#34;&#91;0-9]\.&#91;0-9]\.&#91;0-9]\.)(\*)
```

4. Uncommented the `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">` section and added the following:

```xml
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <FileUpdate Files="properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
                Regex="(?&#60;=AssemblyFileVersion\(&#34;&#91;0-9]\.&#91;0-9]\.&#91;0-9]\.)(\*)"
                ReplacementText="$(Revision)" />
</Target>
```

5. When running MSBuild added the "Revision" property to the command line e.g.

```
msbuild.exe myProject.csproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;Revision=12345
```