# MSbuild for updating the assemblyinfo file

Tags: .net, msbuild, automation, build-automation

I am writing a batch file to automate a series of tasks. One of these tasks is to update the version of the dlls in my solution, by editing the assemblyinfo.cs file in the various projects in my solution; and then finally calling msbuild.exe to compile the solution.

In this regard, is it possible to write a command line script to update the various assemblyinfo.cs files in my .net solution. I would prefer to call msbuild from the commandline itself and not create another msbuild scripted file.

How does one do this using MSBuild? Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks for your time...

Comment: Use msbuild: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562845/how-can-i-change-assembly-version-number-using-assemblyinfotask/4970347#4970347

Comment: does the down-voter have a reason to down vote or is the down-voter just having a bad day?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Editing files with dos cmd batch files is pretty hairy without the help of other tools.
You would need to use something like the for /f command to step through the lines, and then process each line. For example look for the line that starts: "[assembly: AssemblyVersion"
and replace it with something else.

However, if you don't have much in your AssemblyInfo.cs (and remember you can split the AssemblyInfo.cs into multiple cs files if you want) I'd suggest creating the file from scratch with a couple of echo statements.

If you have other tools available like sed.exe the edits can be done easily.

My preference these days would be to go for a trivial powershell script, that could eat this for breakfast and gives you access to the .Net libraries if you need it.

Here's a templating form of it:

```
(Get-Content AssemblyInfo.template.cs) -replace "{version}","1.2.3.4" > AssemblyInfo.cs
```

Here's a form that uses regular expressions to replace whatever version number is there:

```
$x = 'Version("{0}")' -f "1.2.3.4"
$content = Get-Content AssemblyInfo.cs
$content -replace 'Version\(".*"\)',$x > AssemblyInfo.cs
```

Comment: I dont know regular expressions. I tried the line you suggested above and it wiped the AssemblyInfo.cs file clean.

Comment: Sorry about that, the pipeline was truncating the original file before it completed/started reading it. I've edited the example with a fix to read the original content as a separate step.

Answer (score 10):

This is the MSBuild target code where I update all my assemblyinfo.cs files (You have to init AssemblyInfoFilesToUpdate items collections before using this target):

```
  <!-- Update all the assembly info files with generated version info -->
  <Target Name="AfterGet" Condition="'$(ServerBuild)'=='true' And '$(BuildVersion)'!=''">
    <Message Text="Modifying AssemblyInfo files..." />
    <!-- Clear read-only attributes -->
    <Attrib Files="@(AssemblyInfoFilesToUpdate)" Normal="true" />
    <!-- Update AssemblyVersion -->
    <FileUpdate Files="@(AssemblyInfoFilesToUpdate)"
            Regex="AssemblyVersion\(&quot;.*&quot;\)\]"
            ReplacementText="AssemblyVersion(&quot;$(BuildVersion)&quot;)]" />
    <!-- Update AssemblyFileVersion -->
    <FileUpdate Files="@(AssemblyInfoFilesToUpdate)"
            Regex="AssemblyFileVersion\(&quot;.*&quot;\)\]"
            ReplacementText="AssemblyFileVersion(&quot;$(BuildVersion)&quot;)]" />
    <Message Text="AssemblyInfo files updated to version &quot;$(BuildVersion)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

I'm using [FileUpdate task from MSBuildCommunityTasks](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2009/07/03/msbuild-task-to-replace-content-in-text-files.aspx).

Comment: Alternatively you could use the `FileUpdate` task once by specifying the `Regex` argument as `Regex="(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"`.

Comment: @RhysBevilaqua: Could you provide an example (one where AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyVersion are to be the same)?

Comment: You can't just match any line with (\d+\.){3}\d+ because that format of string could exist in other proeprties or comments or whatever. what about your "InternalsVisibleTo" attributes? Those will have version nubmers if you are fully qualifying assemblies.

Answer (score 7):

Isn't there an MS Build task for modifying the assemblyInfo.cs

we have something like this in our publish.proj

```
<Target Name="SolutionInfo">
    <Message Text="Creating Version File:     $(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)"/>


<AssemblyInfo
        CodeLanguage="CS"
        OutputFile="$(BuildInputDir)\SolutionInfo.cs"
        AssemblyTitle="$(Company) $(Product)$(ProductAppendix)"
        AssemblyDescription="$(Company) $(Product)$(ProductAppendix)"
        AssemblyCompany="$(Company)"
        AssemblyProduct="$(Product)"
        AssemblyCopyright="Copyright © $(Company)"    
        ComVisible="false"
        CLSCompliant="false"
        Guid="9E77382C-5FE3-4313-B099-7A9F24A4C328"
        AssemblyVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)"
        AssemblyFileVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: can I put that in my batch file? I am looking for something I can call out from my batch file like so... msbuild {whole bunch of parameters following here..}

Comment: @user20358 sure just put it into a .proj file and call MSBuild with something like this: "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /nologo /verbosity:normal publish.proj  %* /property:ReleaseTier=stable

Answer (score 3):

A fairly old question with an accepted answer, but I also (due to limitations on the CI build server) wanted to do this via a batch file instead of powershell or MS Build Tasks. Here is what I came up with - assumes the solution directory is the current directory:

**SetVersion.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if [%1] == [] GOTO :USAGE
set version=%1
set fileversion=%1
set informationalversion=%1

if [%2] NEQ [] SET fileversion=%2
if [%3] NEQ [] SET informationalversion=%3

echo Setting assembly version information

for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b Assemblyinfo.cs') do (
    echo ^> %%f

    pushd %%~dpf

    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%g in ("AssemblyInfo.cs") do (
        set ln=%%g
        set skip=0

        if "!ln:AssemblyVersion=!" NEQ "!ln!" set skip=1
        if "!ln:AssemblyFileVersion=!" NEQ "!ln!" set skip=1
        if "!ln:AssemblyInformationalVersion=!" NEQ "!ln!" set skip=1

        if !skip!==0 echo !ln! >> AssemblyInfo.cs.versioned
    )

    echo [assembly: AssemblyVersion^("%version%"^)] >> AssemblyInfo.cs.versioned
    echo [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion^("%fileversion%"^)] >> AssemblyInfo.cs.versioned
    echo [assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion^("%informationalversion%"^)] >> AssemblyInfo.cs.versioned

    copy /y AssemblyInfo.cs AssemblyInfo.cs.orig
    move /y AssemblyInfo.cs.versioned AssemblyInfo.cs

    popd
)
echo Done^^!

GOTO:EOF

:USAGE
echo Usage:
echo.
echo SetVersion.bat Version [FileVersion] [InformationalVersion]
echo.
```

**Explanation**

Basically this will recurse all the subfolders and identify AssemblyInfo.cs files, and then line-by-line copy the files to a new file. If any of the assembly version entries are found they are omitted. Then, at the end of each file, it appends the supplied version numbers.

For those batch gurus out there, some might ask why I prefer using `for /F` with `dir /s` instead of `for /R` to iterate over the files. Basically, its because I find the recursive for to be a bit clunky since it will execute for all sub-directories (not just matching files) when no wildcards are supplied. Using the `dir` command is more consistent and easier to predict.

*Note: This batch file will remove all empty lines from the AssemblyInfo.cs files*

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`WriteCodeFragment` MSBuild Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/writecodefragment-task). Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306142/806690) for an example.