# How to automatically increment BizTalk assemblies File Version in a build

Tags: build, biztalk

I have a solution with various BizTalk projects (maps, schema, etc.)

How can you increment each projects "Assembly File Version" in a build, whilst leaving the "Assembly Version" unchanged?

Comment: Are you looking for an automated or manual way of doing this?  Boatseller answer has given you the manual steps for doing it.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Indeed I missed the "automatically" from the question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project Properties, Application tab, Assembly Information button.

In that dialog, you will see both Assembly version and File version.

Reminder, all the .Net rules apply.  File version is for display in Explorer only, it has no effect on any .Net operation.

The Assembly version can be auto incremented by placing an asterisk in any of the places.

Unfortunately, Assembly File Version does not support the wildcards.  If you Bing 'Increment Assembly "File Version"' a number of alternatives come up.

Comment: Sorry, missed part of the requirement in my question [now updated] ... automatically ... doh!

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of the limitation of the File Version not supporting wildcards in plain C# projects, but I was wondering if there was anything specific about BizTalk projects that needed to be taken care of ... I've seen couple of projects on Codeplex, and also the MSBuild extension

Comment: As BizTalk projects are merely specialized C# projects, any of those methods will work.

Comment: Use PowerShell or MSBuild to increment it automatically see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739493/msbuild-for-updating-the-assemblyinfo-file   This is for updating the Assembly Verion, but it can easily be modified for the Assembly File Version.  Have you also looked at the BizTalk Deployment Framework https://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/   ?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yeap, looking at the BTDF ... can't see anything in it for automatically incrementing the File Version