# How to set default build number in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

When you are not using .Net Core you could define your Assembly version in `AssemblyInfo.cs` like so `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.1.3.*")]`. Note in particular the `*` which means the [default build number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx)

In .Net core as far as I can tell the build number is set in the `*.csproj` file. However, it appears to not like using an `*` in version. It complains that version number is invalid.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyVersion>2.1.3.*</AssemblyVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have raised an issue on the [dotnet/cli](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6923) project, but to no avail.

So my question is 'How to set default build number in .Net Core'?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019832/auto-versioning-in-visual-studio-2017-net-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Versioning in Visual Studio 2017 (.NET Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019832/auto-versioning-in-visual-studio-2017-net-core)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is have your build system pass in the version on the CLI. For example if you were using powershell and appveyor you could pass `dotnet build -c Release /p:Version=2.1.3.$env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER`