# How to auto increment asp.net core application version via shell script in TFS Build Job after TFS 2017 Build and show it in the footer of index.html

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm using TFS 2017 for CI, Version defined in csproj file as below should be auto-incremented after every TFS build,

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Major Condition=" '$(Major)' == '' ">1</Major>
    <Minor Condition=" '$(Minor)' == '' ">0</Minor>
    <Patch Condition=" '$(Patch)' == '' ">0</Patch>
    <VersionPrefix>$(Major).$(Minor).$(Patch)</VersionPrefix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I added Major, Minor  and Patch  varibles on TFS Job, my question is how to increment these variables in TFS BUILD.

Comment: It is not directly a solution for you problem but maybe another approach. Take a look at GitVersion if you use Git and Git flow as code version system. For TFS2017 you could just use a build task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by using [Bump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bump) to increment version in package.json file,

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bump = require('gulp-bump');

// Basic usage:
// Will patch the version
gulp.task('bump', function(){
  gulp.src('./component.json')
  .pipe(bump())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// Defined method of updating:
// Semantic
gulp.task('bump', function(){
  gulp.src('./*.json')
  .pipe(bump({type:'minor'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// Defined method of updating:
// Semantic major
gulp.task('bump', function(){
  gulp.src('./package.yml')
  .pipe(bump({type:'major'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// Defined method of updating:
// Set a specific version
gulp.task('bump', function(){
  gulp.src('./*.json')
  .pipe(bump({version: '1.2.3'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// Update bower, component, npm at once:
gulp.task('bump', function(){
  gulp.src(['./bower.json', './component.json', './package.json'])
  .pipe(bump({type:'major'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// Define the key for versioning off
gulp.task('bump', function(){
  gulp.src('./package.json')
  .pipe(bump({key: "appversion"}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

icreated 3 Jobs in TSF, evry job is responsable for incrementing one of Major, Minor and Patch, so while commiting developer will choose to excute one of these jobs, wich will excute the concrete gulp Task.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is stored in TFS server there is one way to update your project. I recommend update your project to .net core 2 downloading dependencies of version. Then update your project file. here is good article of updating your version.

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/upgrading-to-asp-net-core-2-0

Comment: my problem is about defining a version for each release.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the [build number format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#build-number-format) as `$(Major).$(Minor)-rev$(Rev:.rr)`, then update the application version with the variable `$(Build.BuildNumber)`

> **What is $(Rev:.rr)?**
>
> To ensure that every completed build has a unique name. When a build
> is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev
> integer value is incremented by one.
>
> Source:[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190719(v=vs.120).aspx#rev)

You can use the [.NET Core CLI tool](https://github.com/TAGC/dotnet-setversion) to update the version information in .NET Core *.csproj files.

---

Other threads may helps:

- [Versioning .NET Core in Visual Studio Team Services](https://sgryphon.wordpress.com/2017/02/24/versioning-net-core-in-visual-studio-team-services/)
- [Automatically incrementing assembly version of the ASP.NET Core RC2
  application](http://the-coderok.azurewebsites.net/2016/06/14/Automatically-incrementing-assembly-version-of-the-ASP-NET-Core-RC2-application/)
- [TFS Build 2015 and versioning](https://intovsts.net/2015/08/24/tfs-build-2015-and-versioning/)

Comment: i'm trying to use  [lProject Version Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrtarantula.projectversiontools) extension with TFS,
build complete successfully but i didn't find the version in csproj file

Comment: @BoubakrEchieb Seems it's not available for .net core application. The version info can be retrieved from the AssemblyInfo.cs file, it is being created dynamically in the folder: `obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/`. See [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019832/auto-versioning-in-visual-studio-2017-net-core) for details.