# Visual Studio 2019 C# defaulting AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion

Tags: c#, versioning

I am part of a team of WPF developers.  We update the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion in the AssemblyInfo.cs of each assembly when needed, and check it in to GIT.  Then we use MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VersionNumber.targets to update the version of the assembly when we build.

I recently upgraded to VS2019 and now the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion is reset every time I build, to a number corresponding to today's date (eg 1.0.0310.00).  It is happening to everyone who upgraded to 2019, but nobody else.  Did something change in VS2019, or should we look somewhere else?

Comment: has the project target framework, and version changed (besides ide change)?

Comment: The .NET framework version changed many times over the years, nothing else.  And when compiled in VS2017 it behaves as expected.

Comment: VS 2019 got a new msbuid. don't know the exact version difference, but there was a change. Maybe this could help track it down

Comment: this question is for .net core, but maybe help for you as well. since they are both using new VS versions. [Auto Versioning in Visual Studio 2017 (.NET Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019832/auto-versioning-in-visual-studio-2017-net-core/46985624#46985624)

Comment: It seems to be .net core specific