# .NET Core project - how to auto increment the build number with each release build?

Tags: c#, .net-core

In a .NET framework project i would use a class to automatically alter the AssemlyInfo.cs file at build time. In .NET Core it seems the AssemblyInfo.cs is missing. How do you automatically update the release build (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4) with each release build?

Comment: AssemblyInfo.cs is just a class containing attributes. There is no special Framework specific feature to have that or not. So if you have code that changes attributes and that attributes still exist in your NET Core version it should still work.

Comment: you can't do that on your build directly, you ned to updatre your `AssemblyInfo.cs`-file. However you may simply edit that file within your CI-pipeline to include the CI.build-number.

Comment: You have a release-pipeline, don't you?

Comment: see: [Auto Versioning in Visual Studio 2017 (.NET Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019832/auto-versioning-in-visual-studio-2017-net-core)

Comment: Yes i could do it in CI, but i want the build number to be also be set when building directly.

Comment: Then you'll need to add something to your code base to do it - there's nothing built in. MinVer is one common option: https://github.com/adamralph/minver. As others have commented, this is typically handled by CI.

Comment: I can't see much point in doing that locally. Imgaine you build your project on your machine, while another dev also builds the project. Which build-number should the assembly get? Yours or that one from other collegue?

Comment: In an SDK-style project the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file is not generated and not used by default. Instead, you set msbuild [properties for assembly info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/set-attributes-project-file). A build pipeline can maintain the version and inject the correct property value. But you can also set the value in MSBuild code and commit the change. Everyone builds with the same version number. When the version is revised, the new version is manually updated and committed.

Comment: In general, I think it is good practice for the "build" to have no knowledge of the version control system and no knowledge of the pipeline system. The pipeline needs to know about version control and how to start whatever tool is used to "build" and the pipeline can pass values to the build (like a version control revision number). This way the "build" can happen even without version control or a pipeline and those services can be changed without modifying the build logic.